# How can I apply a boolean function to each element in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, random, boolean

```
def bool_gen(p):
   p = float(p)
   if p > 100 or p < 0:
     p = 0.5
   elif 1 <= p <= 100:
     p = p / 100

   return random.random() < p

def apply_discount(v, b):

    if b == True:
       v = v * 0.5
       return v
    elif b == False:
       return v


p = int(random.randint(0,200))
b = bool_gen(p)       
purchases_prices = [20,30,40,50]
have_discount = []
no_discount = []
for each_price in purchases_prices: 
   if b == True    
      have_discount.append(apply_discount(each_price,b))
        
   elif b == False:   
       no_discount.append(apply_discount(each_price,b))
```

I want to ***to apply bool_gen to each element in purchases_prices*** and **not to the whole list**.
What happens:

```
have_discount = [10, 15, 20] and no_discount = []
```

What i'm looking for:

```
have_discount = [10,20]  and no_discount = [30]
```

Comment: Don't use `elif` if the condition is the exact opposite of the `if` condition. Just use `else:`

Comment: What should the result of `bool_gen()` be if `p` is between 0 and 1? Neither of your `if` conditions handle that case.

Comment: ty but it keeps doing the same...not applying func apply_discount to each element on purchases_prices list

Comment: I think it returns 1% p.e

Comment: That wasn't meant as a solution, it was just general coding advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `bool_gen()` inside the loop.

```
for each_price in purchases_prices: 
    b = bool_gen(p)
    if b: 
        have_discount.append(apply_discount(each_price,b))
    else:   
        no_discount.append(apply_discount(each_price,b))
```

Comment: This actually does what i want, however it stopped applying the discount on the have_discount

Comment: what i mean, is that teh apply discount stopped worked returning v * 0.5 when bool_gen(b) is true

Comment: If `p` is very close to 0 or 100, `bool_gen()` will return the same result most of the time.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't setting `b` in the loop, and it's used in the call to `apply_discount()`.

Comment: Why do you need to call `apply_discount()` in the `no_discount` case?

Comment: because the apply function is functioning randomly...so i can store both events(the one when is applied(b = True) and when is not applied(b = False))

Comment: Ty very much! I reached what i wanted but your help was crucial!